# React's map function problem with the sample

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to view data using below sample. my `list.js` file as below:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Person} from './Person';
export class List extends Component {
    render() {
        const persons = [
            {
                name:'Frank',
                age:30,
                city:'city 01'
            },
            {
                name:'Hameed',
                age:25,
                city:'city 02'
            },
            {
                name:'Jack',
                age:24,
                city:'city 03'
            }
        ]
      
        const personList = persons.map(person => <Person person={person}/>)
            return <div> {personList} </div>
       
    }
}
```

My `person.js` file is as below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
export function Person (person){
    return (
        <div>
               {person.name}
        </div>
    );

}
```

I need to print my array value inside the HTML but still did not render the view. I could not fix this.

My `App.js` file as below:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { List} from './components/List'
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <List></List>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: try to close the tag when you render the list : <List />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the prop `person` to each `<Person />`, but inside the `<Person />` component you are not getting it well. Each prop you pass, is getting to the function under the `props` variable, Try this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
export function Person (props){
    return (
        <div>
               {props.person.name}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Or, alternatively, using destructuring:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
export function Person ({ person }){
    return (
        <div>
               {person.name}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `<Person />` component you wrongly used `props`, try instead as:

```
export function Person (props) {
   const { person } = props

   // ... rest
}
```

See the difference from `Person (person)` to `Person ({ person })`. In the explained solution the `person` is ***destructured*** from `props`.

Answer (score 0):

person.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
export const Person = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
               {props.person.name}
        </div>
    );
}
```

or,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
export function Person (props){
    return (
        <div>
               {props.person.name}
        </div>
    );
}
```